# Why is my Galaxy S4 still not appearing as a device in Mac OS X

Tags: adb, samsung-galaxy-s-4, macos

I am trying to solve the problem of having an empty list of devices when running `adb devices`. Why is it not appearing?

I have tried the following to no avail:

- Installed Kies and ran Tools > Install driver; then restarted
- Turned off the Mac OS X firewall in
- run `sudo adb devices` instead of just `adb devices`
- Read the user manual from Samsung, which simply refers me to use Kies
- Attach S4 to a different macbook in case the USB input is faulty
- Try both different USB inputs in my Macbook Pro

The output I see after doing a fresh restart and plugging in the S4:

```
./adb devices
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
List of devices attached
```

(with nothing more shown underneath)

Also, even after installing the drivers using Kies, the device does not appear there.

I am running OS X 10.9 on a Macbook Pro. The phone lights up and does start to charge when it is plugged in to any of the 2 USB ports on my Macbook.

What else can I try to have my brand new S4 appear in this device list?

**EDIT** It seems according to this thread (http://forums.androidcentral.com/samsung-galaxy-s4/282817-pc-cant-detect-galaxy-s4.html) that it may just be a faulty cable. I'm currently using the cable that came with the S4. I'll try other cables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answer: I was using the cable that Samsung provided with the phone

Solution: Go get a USB<>MiniUSB cable that was provided with a digital SLR a few years back and use that instead. The S4 now appears in the adb output and in Kies just fine.

<sarcasm>Thankyou Samsung</sarcasm>

Comment: Same issue and same resolution for a brand new Samsung Galaxy S7 (in addition to enabling Developer Options and USB Debugging).

Answer (score 4):

If using a better cable doesn't work be sure to enable the **USB debugging** feature under **Developer options > Debugging**

Comment: Enable USB Debugging mode solve the problem! For those who don't know how to enable it (it's very hidden on Android 4.3 onward), see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16707137/967945).

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me: try unlock screen after phone is connected. Screen lock seems to block access to the device from USB as well it seems.