# How to connect Samsung Galaxy S4 Zoom to MAC?

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, samsung-kies

I have been unsuccessful in my attempts to connect my Samsung Galaxy S4 Zoom (os 4.2.2) to my Macbook Pro Retina running OSX 10.8.4. I have Kies for MAC installed, I'm connecting my device with a USB, and I'm Scanning for devices using Kies via Wi-Fi on my phone. No luck, this shouldn't be a terribly difficult thing, does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have the proper USB driver for the Zoom installed to be recognised by the Mac?

Comment: Yes, but I just found my solution [here](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/61641/why-is-my-galaxy-s4-still-not-appearing-as-a-device-in-mac-os-x). I just had to use a different USB Cable. Someone can go ahead and mark this question as a duplicate.

Comment: Duplicate: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/61641/why-is-my-galaxy-s4-still-not-appearing-as-a-device-in-mac-os-x

Answer (score 0):

Try a different USB cable, for some reason not all cables will connect your device as a Media Device.